# Qt5 noisy debug messages "XI2 mouse release ... source MouseEventNotSynthesized"

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt5, messaging

How to suppress Qt5 debug messages like

```
XI2 mouse motion 331,150, time 188607671, source MouseEventNotSynthesized
```

that are flooding the console when running a debug release of my GUI program?

Prehistory and analysis: After recent upgrade of Debian (buster) packet libqt5core5a to version 5.9.2+dfsg-6, Qt5 no longer printed debug messages. Neither `qDebug() << ...` nor `qDebug(...)` worked. In my program, these messages are handled through a global function

```
void messageHandler(QtMsgType type, QMessageLogContext const& ctx, rcstr msg) {
    switch (type) {
    case QtDebugMsg:
        std::cerr << ".... " << msg.toStdString() << /*context(ctx) <<*/ "\n" << std::flush;
        break;
    ...
   }
}
```

which is activated by the statement

```
qInstallMessageHandler(messageHandler);
```

After the upgrade, `qDebug` statements would no longer cause invocation of `messageHandler`.

This unwanted behavior is due to file `/etc/xdg/QtProject/qtlogging.ini`, which comes with `libqt5core5a`, and has the contents

```
[Rules]
*.debug=false
```

Following http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html I overwrote these settings by the statement

```
QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules("*.debug=true");
```

in my code. Indeed my debug messages reappeared. However, along with them the unwanted messages described in the opening began to flood the console. From the Qt documentation it is clear that filter rules can be refined like

```
QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules("*.debug=true;foo.bar.debug=false");
```

After this long prehistory and analysis, my question is simply: what to put in place of `foo.bar` to get rid of the mouse motion messages?

Comment: Having looked at the source, try `qt.qpa.input.events`.  Note, also, that I think you can set the environment variable [`QT_LOGGING_RULES`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html#setFilterRules) rather than having to recompile every time you change it.

Comment: does not work: `qt.core.logging: Ignoring malformed logging rule: '*.debug=true;qt.qpa.input.events=false'` or `qt.core.logging: Ignoring malformed logging rule: '*.debug=true;qt.qpa.input.events.debug=false'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules("*.debug=true\nqt.*.debug=false");
```

This generalizes the answer indicated in the comment by @G.M., and it corrects [a bug in the Qt doc](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-66050): the separator needs to be `"\n"`, not `";"`.

Comment: This actually disables all info and warning messages from Qt, too. To reset to the defaults, use  

QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules("\*.debug=true;qt.\*.debug=false");